# Typing lower case 'i' anywhere in Ubuntu 12.04 causes a 'no sign' to appear. Hitting 8 causes my window to maximize

Tags: 12.04, keyboard

I have no idea what I've done, but this morning, I think I might have fat-fingered the keyboard and now whenever I type a lower case **i** a no sign pops up (circle with diagonal slash).

Unusually enough, a capital I doesn't invoke this. And lastly, half the time when I do hit a lower case **i**, ether the i doesn't end up getting typed, or the following letter doesn't get typed.

With all the **i**'s in this post, you can image it took me a while to type this.

Oh great, as I was typing this, I found out that typing 8 or asterisk (*) causes the window to maximize. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Update: I plugged in an external keyboard and the same keys (i,8,*) are not causing any issues.  So it seems its my laptop keyboard, as if a key or combination of keys are stuck, or maybe some wire got grounded? Using 8 as a guide, what combination of keys with an 8 or (*) would cause a window to toggle maximize?

Comment: So, I'm noticing that more often now I'm having this issue. It only happens with lower case 'i', '8' and '*' (at least that's what I've hit). I think I need a new keyboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it appears that this was due to a faulty keyboard. I had a new Dell laptop keyboard sent in and I replaced it. It came with everything except the ribbon cable connecting the motherboard to the keyboard control circuit (there are several ribbon cables on they keyboard itself connecting to a single control circuit).

After using this it appears that the old keyboard was broken. There wasn't anything apparent such as a frayed ribbon wire.  But, with such unusual things occurring this outcome makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

This should give you some options, and potentially a "test your keyboard layout and we'll tell you what it should be" sort of input.

Comment: So I ended up plugging in an external keyboard, and by the time I went to show another coworker, the problem had stopped. I ran what you suggested and nothing really stood out.  I'm wondering then if I just have a faulty keyboard and somehow something was getting grounded.